# What are the benefits of using the RelayCommand object

Tags: mvvm-light

I want to know what the advantage are using the relay command to call functions that refresh the screen.  In my application I have the following relay command setup.

```
private RelayCommand _refreshSitesCommand;
    public RelayCommand RefreshSitesCommand
    {
        get { return _refreshSitesCommand ?? (_refreshSitesCommand = new RelayCommand(RefreshSites)); }
    }

    private RelayCommand _refreshProvidersCommand;
    public RelayCommand RefreshProvidersCommand
    {
        get { return _refreshProvidersCommand ?? (_refreshProvidersCommand = new RelayCommand(RefreshProviders)); }
    }

    private async void RefreshSites()
    {
        var sitesStats = await _dataService.GetSiteStats();

        if (sitesStats != null)
        {
            SiteStats.Clear();

            foreach (var site in sitesStats)
            {
                SiteStats.Add(new SiteStatsViewModel(site));
            }

            SelectedSite = SiteStats[0];
        }
    }

    private async void RefreshProviders()
    {
        var providers = await _dataService.GetProviders();

        if (providers != null)
        {
            Providers.Clear();

            foreach (var provider in providers)
            {
                Providers.Add(new ProviderViewModel(provider));
            }

            SelectedProvider = Providers[0];
        }
    }
```

Then in my code I have the following calls to execute it.

```
RefreshProvidersCommand.Execute(null);
RefreshSitesCommand.Execute(null);
```

So why is that better than just calling the RefreshSites and RefreshProviders functions. Then I would not need the code for the RelayCommand objects.  Other than exposing the functionality of the 2 private functions, what benefit does using the RelayCommand object have over just making the functions public and calling them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can bind to a Command in your view. You can't bind to methods in your views (well you can but binding to Commands is much cleaner)

Comment: OK, so it makes it so it would be easy for me to bind a button to run the refreshSitesCommand when presses.  And that would be in place of having a click/tap event for the button and then calling the public function. Correct?

Answer (score 5):

MVVM is in part about avoiding code-behind in the View class.

If, for example, you want an action to be taken in response to a button click, then you can either assign a Click event handler or assign the Command property to command methods. (Commands have certain advantages over Click event handlers, but that was not the question.)

There is no other good option for handling the Click event other than defining a method in the View class.  You cannot directly assign the Click event to a handler method in a different class than the View and you can bind only to properties, not methods.

However, you can assign the Command property to a **binding** to an **object** that implements the ICommand interface, e.g. a RelayCommand, and that binding can be to a property of your ViewModel object.  This avoids having to define Click event handlers in the view's code behind file and at the same time gives your ViewModel the ability to easily enable/disable commands without needing to know anything about the View's specific implementation.

One can argue about the merits of religiously avoiding code-behind, but that was not the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

RelayCommand also implements a CanExecute method which, when binding your RelayCommand to a button, is used to automatically toggle the button's IsEnabled property based on the action you specified for the CanExecute method.